# D3.js and Knockout Force Diagram API Updates

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, d3.js, force-layout

I have a D3 force diagram http://jsbin.com/dakuy/4/edit which calls data externally using $.getJSON from a Knockout form:

```
function searchModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.searchCanlii = ko.observable(" ");
}

function SearchViewModel() {
    self.onSubmit = function(){
```

However, each time the form is submitted, the diagram is duplicated. Can the diagram be updated on a submission without the duplication? Note that for now I use the search term "Canada" for testing as some terms produce errors because of certain canlii outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the old SVG just prior to creating the new one using:

```
d3.select("svg")
   .remove();
```

See this question: [How can I remove or replace SVG content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784018/how-can-i-remove-or-replace-an-svg-content)