# How do I create the update function in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to build a bar graph that I can switch between the amount of data displayed based on a particular length of time. So far the code that I have is this,

```
var margin = {
    top : 20,
    right : 20,
    bottom : 30,
    left : 50
}, width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right, height = 500
        - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var barGraph = function(json_data, type) {

if (type === 'month')
    var barData = monthToArray(json_data);
else 
    var barData = dateToArray(json_data);


    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([ 0, Math.round(Math.max.apply(null,
            Object.keys(barData).map(function(e) {
                return barData[e]['Count']}))/100)*100 + 100]).range(
            [ height, 0 ]);

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([ 0, width ], .1)
            .domain(d3.entries(barData).map(function(d) {
                return barData[d.key].Date;
            }));

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width",
            width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height",
            height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr(
            "transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform",
            "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).append(
            "text").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em").style("text-anchor", "end").text(
                    "Total Hits");

    svg.selectAll(".barComplete").data(d3.entries(barData)).enter()
            .append("rect").attr("class", "barComplete").attr("x",
                    function(d) {
                        return x(barData[d.key].Date)
                    }).attr("width", x.rangeBand() / 2).attr("y",
                    function(d) {
                        return y(barData[d.key].Count);
                    }).attr("height", function(d) {
                return height - y(barData[d.key].Count);
            }).style("fill", "orange");

    var bar = svg.selectAll(".barHits").data(d3.entries(barData))
            .enter().append("rect").attr("class", "barHits").attr(
                    "x", function(d) {
                        return x(barData[d.key].Date) + x.rangeBand() / 2
                    }).attr("width", x.rangeBand() / 2).attr("y",
                    function(d) {
                        return y(barData[d.key].Count);
                    }).attr("height", function(d) {
                return height - y(barData[d.key].Count);
            }).style("fill", "red");
};
```

This does a great job displaying my original data set, I have a button set up to switch between the data sets which are all drawn at the beginning of the page. all of the arrays exist but no matter how hard I try I keep appending a new graph to the div so after the button click I have two graphs, I have tried replacing all of the code in the div, using the enter() exit() remove() functions but when using these I get an error stating that there is no exit() function I got this by following a post that someone else had posted [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) and another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052694/how-to-update-d3-js-bar-chart-with-new-data) but to no avail. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Can you create the fiddle, so it will be easy to fix it.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa http://jsfiddle.net/926e7upb/8/embedded/result/ here ya go, I just created this fiddle hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

What you are most likely doing is drawing a new graph probably with a new `div` each time the button is clicked, one thing you can try doing is to hold on to the charts container element somewhere, and when the button is clicked, you simply clear it's children and re-draw the graphs.

Comment: Okay so this is partially correct and now I just need to know how to fix it, its not redrawing the div everytime but it is creating a new instance of the graph every time. So what I am saying is that everytime a different button is clicked the svg element is duplicated instead of replaced? any ideas?

Comment: Yes, suppose you have the graphs sitting inside a `g` element, you will need to use a selector that selects that element, clears everything (or the graphs at least) inside it, and then redraw the graph in that element.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, I almost never chain `.data()` and `.enter()`.

```
// This is the syntax I prefer:
var join  = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)
var enter = join.enter()

/* For reference: */

// Selects all rects currently on the page
// @returns: selection
svg.selectAll('rect') 

// Same as above but overwrites data of existing elements
// @returns: update selection
svg.selectAll('rect').data(data) 

// Same as above, but now you can add rectangles not on the page
// @returns: enter selection
svg.selectAll('rect').data(data).enter()
```

Also important:

> [#](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter) selection.enter()
>
> The enter selection merges into the update selection when you append or insert.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, but not fully. But I am also unsure if we are on the same page. The data that I am trying to insert is completely different data all together. What I am doing is switching from a 7 day view, to a 30 day view to a monthly view for three months, and also to a monthly view for six months, so not only am I updating data but I am redrawing the entire graph, I hope this helps explain the question a little more, and if the answer remains the same, I am not as familiar with D3 as I would like to be so if it is possible could you elaborate please?

Comment: Oh and here is the fiddle I created for someone asking earlier maybe it will help you to understand my problem, http://jsfiddle.net/926e7upb/8/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out So I will first direct all of your attention to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784018/how-can-i-remove-or-replace-svg-content) Where I found my answer. The key was in the way I was drawing the svg element, instead of replacing it with the new graph I was just continually drawing a new one and appending it to the #chart div. I found the answer that I directed you guys to and added this line in the beginning of my existing barGraph function.

```
d3.select("#barChart").select("svg").remove();
```

and it works like a charm, switches the graphs back and forth just as I imagined it would, now I have a few more tasks for the bargraph itself and I can move on to another project.

Thank you all for all of your help and maybe I can return the favor one day!