# D3 React - Cannot remove map of paths before drawing paths with new locations

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to programatically draw a map of SVG paths using D3 in React. Every time I render a new map of paths, the previously drawn paths are not removed from the DOM.

I have tried all suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784018/how-can-i-remove-or-replace-svg-content), but none are working effectively.

When I click a button, a new node is added to an array and D3 draws a SVG path from its starting point. But at render-time previously drawn lines still appear.

Here is my code:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = d3
            .select(svgRef.current)
            .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${avaliableHorizontalSpace} ${avaliableHorizontalSpace}`);

        svg.select('path').remove(); // this doesn't work
        svg.selectAll("*").remove(); // only one stays drawn using this

        if (rects.length > 0) {
            rects.forEach((_el, idx) => {
                const line = d3
                    .line<Number>()
                    .x((value, index) => 200 * index)
                    .y((value) => Number(value));

                svg
                    .selectAll(`.node[nodeid='${nodes[idx][0].id}]'`)
                    .data([rects])
                    .join('path')
                    .attr('d', (value: (Number[] | Iterable<Number>)[]) => {
                        return line(value[idx]);
                    });
            });
        }
    }, [rects]);
```

Later in JSX:

```js
    const NodePathWithId = (props: NodePathWithId): ReactElement => {
        return (<path {...props} />);
    };
 
...

    {rects.length > 0 && rects.map((el, idx) => (
        <svg
            fill="white"
            fillOpacity="0"
            stroke="#000"
            strokeWidth="1.5"
            ref={(ref): void => { svgRef.current = ref; }}
            style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
            key={`y${nodes[idx][0].id}`}
        >
            <NodePathWithId nodeid={nodes[idx][0].id} />
        </svg>
    ))}
```

How do I update the SVG to remove old paths so I only have the number of paths in the `rects` array?

#### Update:

Some picture below to demonstrate the problem:
First click
[image]
Second click:
[image]

Comment: Why do you render multiple `<svg>`s? You can put all your paths under a single one...

Comment: Hi @MichaelRovinsky, thanks - well I tried storing it as a ref and it doesn't render on the first render. I have tried it in other locations but the same issue above persists. Where do you suggest I put it considering it needs to access the svg ref?

Comment: Have added some screen shots for context